# Query Execution method in Spark/Impala

Tags: apache-spark-sql, impala, pyspark

Could someone advise what is the query execution method in PySpark? Impala query execution is faster than hive query execution however when we run the same queries via Pyspark it is taking long how would we get the impala execution method via Pyspark?

Comment: Thanks Samson,
I am welldeserved this answer.
BTW, Would be able to help on getting better performance on query execution via Pyspark. Currently i am through spark.sql() which was defined as 
spark = SparkSession.builder.enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate(). Is there any other way i can execute?

Comment: You really should read about WHAT is Spark, versus Hive, versus Impala, versus Presto, etc. >> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60359882/how-can-i-make-the-pyspark-and-sparksql-to-execute-the-hive-on-spark/60365581 for a very rough overview

Comment: And you should really define your needs: batch, interactive? strict SLA? What is your "time budget" vs. "compute budget" vs. "storage budget" for each task, i.e. do you want speed at any cost, or will your system admins yell at you if you trash their cluster with low-priority tasks on high-priority queues? Can you afford low-latency HDFS storage, or just regular HDFS storage, or is object storage (e.g. S3) sufficient?

Comment: I have hive database in our cluster and want to extract counts of each table in each schema. we have more than 10000 tables across hive db. i tried above hive support and executed via pyspark. which is taking over 15hrs to generate the total row counts.

Comment: OK, that's pretty specific and should be in the _question_ itself. It's a massive, brute force data crunching goal -- you need to iterate on **all** the Metastore entries and **all** the HDFS directories & files for 10k tables. Did you try to run the queries sequentially, or in parallel? Can you afford to preempt all resources in your cluster for several hours?

Comment: Yes, I iterated and ran sequentially it took around 16hours on empty Cluster. I was looking out for any other alternative and quickest solutions.

Comment: If you're collecting statistics on your tables (which is always recommended) then you can use cardinality information, either by parsing `describe` results or directly querying rdbms backing Hive metastore.